# SAML and kerberos what to use where

Tags: authentication, kerberos, saml

I came across SAML and kerberos, both are used to establish identity using assertions (tickets)  so is there an overlap in their use ?

Can somebody highlight their differences and point which technology is a better fit where.

thanks

**update** to add some context, there are some web services in an intranet environment where only a closed set of users should be allowed to access it. Is this requirement better suited for SAML or kerberos

Comment: You might be interested in [Kerberos over the Public Internet](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41803/kerberos-authentication-over-the-public-internet), which bears on your question.

Comment: This is *somewhat* of a broad question.

Comment: @gowenfawr your lead was very helpful, thanks. I have added some context to my question, its a closed system. so key exchange may be a possibility

Answer (score 10):

SAML is used over the Internet. If you have a web application you would use SAML. SAML is just a standard data format for exchanging authentication data. You would typically use it for a web SSO (single sign on).

Kerberos is used in an enterprise LAN typically. Kerberos requires that the user it is authenticating is in the kerberos domain.

Not really a lot of overlap in my opinion.